# Displaying text retrieved from a Java class

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm a beginner in Java. I have a 2 Java file that will passed the text retrieved from one Java file to the main Java file. But it doesnt seems to be working.

Main.java

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class LSAalgo extends Preprocessing {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Preprocessing x = new Preprocessing(?);

}
}
```

Retrieve.java

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Preprocessing {
public void preprocessing(String text) throws IOException
{
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input7.txt"));

        String line;

        while((line = in.readLine()) != null)
        {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
            in.close();

    }
}
```

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just printing the text in console only. If you want to return complete text from one method to other just change your method return type to `String` (Since you are returning text) from `void`. Next change your code to

```
public String preprocessing() throws IOException
{
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input7.txt"));
    String line = "";

      while((line = in.readLine()) != null)
        {
            System.out.println(line);
            line += line;//appending complete text
        }
     in.close();
     return line;//returning text
}
```

In `main(-)` change code to call `preprocessing()` method of `Preprocessing` class.

```
 Preprocessing x = new Preprocessing();
 String text = x.preprocessing();//getting text from Preprocessing class
```

Comment: Hi, Ive added "System.out.println(text);" to ur code and the console only printed out "null". How can I correct it?

Comment: Does `input7.txt` file contains text? @Cael

Comment: Yup. it has a few sentences

Comment: Are you passing any text to `preprocessing(-)`. otherwise `text` will not prints anything. @Cael

Comment: "String text = x.preprocessing("Test");//getting text from Preprocessing class". I've put it the way you do. I just need to print the whole text from the text file. If not what should i put ?

Comment: If you want to print text from text file then there is no need of passing parameter to `preprocessing(-)` method. Just updatesd my answer. @Cael